# Negative imaginary part conductivity

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, electrical-resistance, complex-numbers, many-body

Suppose we have some gas of electrons and we calculate the current as a response to an electric field. In linear response theory we would find in Fourier space
$$
{\bf J}(\omega,q) = \sigma(\omega,q) {\bf E}(\omega,q),
$$
where $\sigma(\omega,q)$ is the conductivity that could for instance be calculated using some fancy many-body techniques. In general the conductivity can be complex. I have two related questions:

1. Is it true that the imaginary part needs to be larger than zero for all values of ($q,\omega$)? If not/so, why? And is there a similar restriction on the real part?
2. What is the relation between real and imaginary parts of $\sigma(q,\omega)$ and the real/imaginary parts of the dielectric function $\epsilon(q,\omega)$? Does this object also need to have an imaginary part larger than zero? And why?

I would greatly appreciate a good reference. I tried looking e.g. in Many-Particle Physics by Mahan, but it does not seem to explain this, probably because it is too basic.

Comment: If I were you, I'd ask those two questions as two separate posts. I can easily answer the first question, but not the second, so I can't post an answer. If the questions we split up I could answer one of them. This is the basic reason it's better to ask *one* question per post: you're more likely to get your questions answered!

Comment: See https://unlcms.unl.edu/cas/physics/tsymbal/teaching/SSP-927/Section%2013_Optical_Properties_of_Solids.pdf